# MVC / IIS rewriting hyperlink?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, iis-6

I am working on a site and on a particular page I have a link with the href:

```
"/Home/Search?search=something"
```

On my dev machine running the ASP.NET development server, I follow the link and everything is gravy.  I click the link, and it appears as written in the URL bar.

However, on the staging server (IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003) if I click the link, it appears in the URL bar as:

```
/Home/Search%3Fsearch=something
```

And then the site throws the error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (?)

Obviously this is from the question mark being converted to '%3F' but I was wondering why this is happening and what the exact mechanism is.  Is there some web.config or other config setting that controls this, or is it a difference between the test server and IIS 6.0 ?

Comment: What's the actual href value of the link? Is it correct, or is it the urlencoded version?

Comment: That is the actual value of the href.

Comment: Then, the question is why it's being urlencoded when rendered to the page, which really has nothing to do with IIS. How are you creating that link or the URL value for the href? Post any relevant code.

Comment: <%="/Home/Search?search=something" %> is how.  That's it.

Comment: Why are you using ASP for a simple string? Just add it directly to the page and see what happens, i.e. `<a href="/Home/Search?search=something">`.

Comment: Or, if the "something" part is dynamic, just use ASP tags for that: `/Home/Search?search=<%=mySearchQuery%>`

Comment: Its not my page, this is one of those things where I've got a block of code I didn't write, and can't really change.  Anyway, even if I could, the question isn't about "what can I change?" it is, "why is this happening?"

Comment: It's happening, I presume, *because* you're using ASP tags to write the string. And, why can't you change this? If you can see code, you can change it, unless there's some silly stipulation that you literally aren't allowed to change anything (even though you have the ability), in which case, what are you doing working on this in the first place? Even if that is the case, you can change it long enough to see if it fixes the problem, and then take it up with whoever you need to, if the solution is valid